# how to use rest-client to display specific data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i connect with api to display specific data but not how to use this rails .
not know put code in `model` or `controller`

need how to use this code to connect rails app

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

url = 'https://xxxx.restdb.io/rest/data'

headers = 
{
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'x-apikey': "-------",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
}
req = RestClient.get(url, headers)

we = JSON.parse(req.body)

p we
```

`config/application.rb` code after updated

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Version0
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('app/services')
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create service folder in the app folder nor can use lib folder, also make a task too.

Make sure restart the server and url-address!

```
#|- app
#|-- services
#|--- restdb_api.rb


require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

class RestdbApi

    def initialize
      @url = 'https://xxxx.restdb.io/rest/data'
      @headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json",
        'x-apikey': "-------",
        'cache-control': "no-cache"
      }
    end    

    def call
        res = RestClient.get(@url, @headers)
        body = JSON.parse(res, { symbolize_names: true })
        body
    end
end

# config/application.rb
   config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('app/services')
```

And call it anywhere in the controller...

```
#if wanna dynamically call url, api key or smth else, just initialize in the class.
rdb = RestdbApi.new
body = rdb.call
puts body
```

Comment: Thansk @7urm3n but i know code but not how to use in rails ?

Comment: @Sdadad updating my post 2min.

Comment: when write `class GdirectionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   rdb = RestdbApi.new
 @x= rdb.call
   
  end
end
` appear this error uninitialized constant GdirectionsController::RestdbApi

Comment: updated post added `config.eager_load_paths`, make sure restart server also

Comment: `config.eager_load_paths` added to `application.rb` in config and restart server but error is retain

Comment: did u add like this ? `config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('app/services')`, cuz i just tested on mine it works properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173908/discussion-between-7urkm3n-and-sdadad).