# How to get specific data from Json and display in Google map in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I connected to DB NOSQL online return JSON value

for example

```
{
  "_id"=>"5b2e880c1de0c46b00001dda",
  "gps_lattitude"=>"30.63",
  "gps_longitude"=>"31.09",
  "gps_speed_kph"=>"0.1",
  "gps_heading"=>"129.36",
  "gsm_csecond"=>58,
  "gsm_second"=>46,
  "gsm_minute"=>35,
  "gsm_hour"=>21,
  "gsm_month"=>6,
  "gsm_day"=>20,
  "gsm_year"=>2018,
  "HWID"=>"AC37439773C8",
  "pulse_rate"=>585,
  "recrdID"=>458
}
```

Need to display `gps_longitude` & `gps_lattitude` to google map

**when working with SQL database, I can do it easily but do not know how can do it using JSON**

Comment: Read a documentation?

Comment: can send link explain that? thanks you

Comment: Try using sqaure brackets to access them: `data['gps_latitude']` (you have an extra "t" there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller:**

```
body  = {gps_lattitude: "40.4967628", gps_longitude: "-80.0584638"}.as_json
@lat  = body["gps_lattitude"]
@long = body["gps_longitude"]
```

**Html Page:**

```
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
    <script>
        // Google Map Init
        function initMap(){
            var lat = "<%= @lat %>";  // sample - "40.4967628"
            var lng = "<%= @long %>"; // sample - "-80.0584638"
            var uluru = {lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng)};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
                zoom: 15,
                center: uluru
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: map
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks you can add my api key ?

Comment: we already done fetching data from url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067983/how-to-use-rest-client-to-display-specific-data-in-rails/51068034#51068034

Comment: api key for google maps like  this  `<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=-------------"></script>`

Comment: @Sdadad take a look this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Thanks you i already have api i write it wrong thanks @7urkm3n for help me :)